# why sender in viewcontroller segue works as opposed to collection view cell segue

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, segue

I have a ViewController that is a CollectionViewDelegate. I wanted to segue to a detail view of the image in my CollectionView when the user taps on the image. I connected the segue from my cell to the detail VC and used this code.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) { 
    //segue to detail view of image
    if segue.identifier == "ShowDetail",
       let detailImageView = segue.destination as? CollectionDetailViewController
    {
        detailImageView.imageName = sender as! UIImage
    }
}
```

The error that showed was "Cannot convert the sender CollectionView to UIImage". Instead when I segued through my VC I was able to cast sender to UIImage. Why is that?

Comment: `detailImageView.imageName` ??? Sounds like it is a String (image *name*). If so, that's why you can't set it to a `UIImage`. If `.imageName` is actually an image, not a string, then what is `sender`? Is it a collection view *cell*? If so, that's why...

Comment: .imageName is an image, bad on my part. Yes the sender is collection view cell, and Im wondering why the sender has to be viewcontroller instead for the casting (sender as! UIImage) to work.

Comment: basically what i mean is by connecting viewcontroller in storyboard to segue, i am able to detect sender as the tapped UIIMage in view. On the other hand, if i connect the collection view cell to segue, it doesnt detect the image defined in the cell, rather it detects sender as the cell itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what or why it is working in code you haven't shown... but in this case, if `sender` is a cell, you cannot simply declare "now you are a UIImage" and thus it is so.

I assume you have a `UIImageView` inside your Collection View Cell, so more likely, you want to do something like:

```
if let cell = sender as? MyCustomCell {
    if let image = cell.theImageView.image as? UIImage {
        detailImageView.imageName = image
    }
}
```

note: I'm just typing this, not running it, so it may need a tweak or two.

Comment: and when i connect the segue using the viewcontroller why is image used as sender, and not the viewcontroller itself?

Comment: As I said, I don't know, because I'm not looking at your project. But trying to guess.... you must have done something else to get `sender` to be a `UIImage`. If it's being called from code, you can, for example, do `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "test", sender: myImage)`.

Comment: thx! i think its because prepareForSegue is only a method for viewcontroller and cant be invoked through objects like collection view cell?

Comment: It's unrelated. Say I have a segue defined - call it "testSegue" - and I have a Collection view... in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` func, I can do `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "testSegue", sender: UIImage(named: "image1"))` ... and then `prepareForSegue` will be triggered, and `sender` will be a `UIImage`. So, again, however you were getting `sender` to be a `UIImage` before, ***something*** was being done. You cannot put a UIImage on a view to begin with, so it certainly was not simply "ctrl-drag" and connect.